# issue with array and views, codeigninter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a model who returns an array like this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["report_title"]=> string(7) "Test #1" ["content"]=> string(24) "This is a test" ["author"]=> string(6) "Thomas" ["create_date"]=> string(10) "1304969836" } }
```

And my control:

```
        $report_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $report = $this->Report_model->getReport($report_id, $company_id);

        if(!$report)
        {
        // TODO: fix this if the getReports returns FALSE;

        } else {
            $data['report'] = $report;
        }

        $this->load->view('user/report_read', $data);
```

My problem is that i can't use the variables in my view. I have tried different ways but i can't get it to work.

my view.

```
echo $report['report_title']; // Error: Message: Undefined index: report_title
echo $report_title; // Error: Undefined variable: report_title
```

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: Your `$data` is array(array(datas …)) so you may try `$report[0]['report_title']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access it correctly the first time ($report['report_title']). Your problem is that your $report is an array of reports. If this is not what you are after, review your model and adjust the return value. If it is, loop through $report with a foreach in your view to output a list of reports. Using your code above, something like this should work:

```
<?php foreach ( $report as $r ): ?>
Title: <?php echo $r['report_title']; ?> <br />
Content: <?php echo $r['report_content']; ?> <br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```